# Bootstrap -> Bootswatch Input - Search not Responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have trouble with the Bootstrap/Bootswatch input field in the navbar. [Example](http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://mond.traum-deutung.de/abstillen-mit-dem-mond/%7C1188%7C762%7C1)

After 1186 px it breaks and the input field makes a new line.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You must post at the very least your HTML code you're using to generate your form. I'd seriously recommend not using that link you provided, as people will find out.. it will create LOTS of redirects when you resize the window, making it virtually impossble to return back to this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the class 'form-control' in your input field?
Your code should look like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```